# How to change a certain number of values in vector after one meeting a condtion in R?

Tags: r, vector, data-manipulation

I have a random vector with 0 and 1 in a certain proportion. Now, I want to change 100 ones to 0 after a 0 occured in the vector. How can I achieve that?

Here is the vector:

```
n <- 100000
a <- round(n/3)
b <- round(a/100)

set.seed(1)
x <- rep(1, n)
x[sample(1:a, b, FALSE)] <- 0
```

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ example, e.g. n = 10-20-ish instead of 100000 and show the desired output.

Comment: What if the difference between two `0` is smaller than 100?

Answer (score 0):

You first get minimum of `which` to locate first `0`. Afterwards, check for any occurrence of `100` and replace that with `0`.

Lets try with small sample:

```
n <- 20
a <- round(n/2)
b <- round(a/4)

set.seed(1)
x <- rep(1, n)
x[sample(1:a, b, FALSE)] <- 0
x[18] = 100  #Change 18th element as 100
x
#[1]   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 100   1   1


# Index of first 0
idx_0 <-  min(which(x==0))
x[idx_0:length(x)] <- 
         ifelse(x[idx_0:length(x)]==100, 0 , x[idx_0:length(x)])

# Modified x
x
# [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

**Edited:** Based on feedback from `OP`. Goal is to update next `n` (say 10) values.

```
idx_0 <-  min(which(x==0))
x[idx_0:min((idx_0+10),length(x))]  <- 0   #Update next 10 values with 0
x
#[1]   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1 100   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i guess I didn't make it clear enough. I want to replace the next 100 values of the vector by 0 after a 0 occured. Taking the 0 as a starting point.

Comment: @Juli Then it would be much easier. Let me update my answer to update next `10` values with `0`

Comment: @Juli Have a look at updated answer. I have added a condition so that it will update next `10` or up to end of vector. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you, MKR 25!

Comment: @Juli Glad it worked for you. You can accept answer by clicking on `tick` symbol at the left of answer box. So that it will be helpful to future users.